# How to register a desktop application for one drive business in new azure website?

Tags: azure, office365, desktop-application, onedrive, office365-restapi

I want to register my desktop application for using one drive business API in azure.But I can't find active directory node anywhere in the site as mentioned on this [link](https://dev.onedrive.com/app-registration.htm#register-your-app-for-onedrive-for-business).Here is the screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its right there, click on browse on the left hand side, and if you don't see it type in the filter [image]

Comment: No, it is not there.I have added the screenshot to the question.

Comment: search for Active Directory in the text box  showing at the top of the blade window.